# Java 11 send http request to 0.0.0.0 delays 5 seconds

Tags: java, httprequest

- I have Java 11.0.1 installed in MacOs Mojave and I started a local
  Vertx http server which listens on http://0.0.0.0:8085/home (Just
  return "hello world").
- However, if I send request to **0.0.0.0:8085/home** programmatically by
  using java, it takes **5** seconds to reach local server. But if I
  send to **localhost:8085/home**, it will immediately reach server and
  receive response.
- Besides, I tried Chrome, cURL and Python to send http request to both
  **0.0.0.0:8085/home** and **localhost:8085/home**, both of them will immediately receive response. So is this a Java 11 bug or not?

  ```
  String url = "http://0.0.0.0:8085/home" // Or http://localhost:8085/home;
  URL obj = new URL(url);
  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
  System.out.println(con.getResponseCode()); // 5 seconds to receive
  ```
- If I use Java 11 Http Client new feature, it will hang forever.

  ```
  HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
  HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create("http://localhost:8085/home")).build();
  HttpResponse response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
  System.out.println(response.statusCode());
  ```

Comment: https://threatbrief.com/0-0-0-0-ip-address-uses/

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is a *wildcard* address that can only be used on the server to say "all IP addresses of my machine". It cannot be used on the client, and I'm amazed that you actually do get a connection using it. Specify your machines real IP address, the machines name, or `localhost`. Never specify `0.0.0.0` when trying to connect to a server. Link in above comment has further detail.

Comment: Most likely, client libraries are detecting the *incorrect* use of `0.0.0.0` and substituting it with something more realistic. That is the only way it could work.  You simply can't connect/send to `0.0.0.0`, but you can listen on it. Maybe Java is actually attempting to connect to `0.0.0.0` and it takes 5 seconds to fail, then Java tries a real IP.  Who knows.

Comment: But I do connect immediately when I typed 0.0.0.0:8085/home in Chrome and only Java blocked 5 seconds to reach server. Furthermore, if I use Java 11 new Http Client feature, it seems it will hang forever.